# Extract all values between { dynamic } and place in a string array

Tags: c#

I need to extract all words between { } brackets and place in a string array.
The problem is that the text between the brackets is dynamic.

For example:

Hi {name}, thanks for visiting {site}

In this text i want to get name and site words place in a array.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have problem with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I guess Regex is what you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to King's answer, this will help you retrieve just the keys without surrounding brackets.

```
Regex.Matches(input, @"\{(?<Value>[^{]+)\}").Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(m=>m.Groups["Value"].Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution :** you can use `Substring()` function to retrieve the part of the string.
**Syntax:** `Substring(int startindex,int length);`

**Steps:**
**1.**  you need to send the starting `index(1)` of `{` to `Substring()` function as first parameter.

**2.**  you need to send the `length` of string to be retrieved that means `index(2)` of `}` in the form of length `(index2-index1)`   to `Substring()` function as second parameter.

Try this:

```
        String  middlevalue="";
        String str = "thanks for visiting {site}";
        int index1= str.IndexOf("{");
        index1++;
        int index2=str.IndexOf("}");

        if(index1!=-1 && index2!=-1)
        middlevalue=str.Substring(index1, (index2 - index1)));
```

**Output:**

`middlevalue` contains ->  `site`

Answer (score 2):

`Regex` should work for you, note that all the words between `{...}` should not contain any `{...}`.

```
var items = Regex.Matches(input, "\{[^{]+\}").Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(m=>m.Value.Trim('{','}')).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var regex = @"(?<=\{)[^}]*(?=\})";
var text = "Hello my name is {James}";

var matches = Regex.Matches(text, regex);
```